# how to add ref from forwardref component without rendering?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, use-ref

I'm passing a dom node to a mapbox popup.
I've a component P.js which consists of forward ref as

```
import React  from "react";

const P = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return  <p {...props} ref={ref}></p>
})
export default P;
```

I'm importing it in App.js as

```
import P from './P';
......

const pRef = useRef(null)
console.log(pRef)
const p = <P ref={pRef}/>
console.log(pREf)

const App = () => {
useEffect(() => {
..... //codes
marker.setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup().setDOMContent(pRef.current))

})  

}
```

How can i pass that ref rendering on another component and running in another?

In my case i tried to make another const to add value

```
const p = <P ref={pRef}/>
```

I think, this is not way to passing ref from another component, so it is not rendered.
Is there any methods in Marker component , that i can pass ref if instead to load dom content .
Thank you for helping.

Comment: Do you mean something like https://twitter.com/realamirhe/status/1362457891609919489?

Comment: @Amirhe i think it did worked, putting <P ref={pRef}> on return of app.js,  but it made that dom p content visible to whole map , their , is there any way , without using it on return, please, Thank you

Comment: I guess I could solve it, let me know if there is any gray area or problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest using this react wrapper around the `mapbox-gl` named [react-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl)

You can do the method mentioned in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/realamirhe/status/1362457891609919489) and put some style in your P tag to make it invisible by the way

```
<P class="hide">Hello world</P>
```

```css
.hide { display: none } /* or any other that fits for you e.g. visibility hidden */
```

You can also use `renderToString` to convert your component to HTML string on the fly.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

const P = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <p {...props} ref={ref}></p>;
});

export default function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    marker.setPopup(
      new mapboxgl.Popup().setDOMContent(
        // render your Paragraph component exactly to html
        renderToString(<P>Hello world</P>),
      ),
    );
  });

  return <div id="map" />;
}
```

Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-forest-4t2om?file=/src/App.js) for showing it works.

You can also pass the exact same string representation of your paragraph component suggested by a package [doc](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup/)

```js
const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
.setHTML('<h1>Hello World!</h1>') // here is the string representation
.addTo(map);
```

If you want to work with the js package duo to legacy issue, there is also a package that helps you to add a custom tiny react wrapper around the package to work with called [react-aptor](https://github.com/amirHossein-Ebrahimi/react-aptor)